# how to keep old control in place holder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

we add some control to place holder.when page is run , i want add a control to place holder.but old control dispose .code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" ClientIDMode="AutoID" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" Interval="15000" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnTick="TimerUpdate_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhChats" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

i do chat.when page load i add old chat in place holder.when user write message and send it.how can add this message in end of place holder without add old message?
my code for time is:

```
foreach (var chat in listChatsNewToShow)
{
    plhChats.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Concat("<div class=\"\">", chat.Message, "</div>")));
}
UpdatePanel2.Update();
```

how can add message with keep old message in place holder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get out place holder from update panel .